# Could not find com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4 react-native-video in Android

Tags: android, react-native, react-native-video

I want to use `react-native-video` in my project. After installing this package I got this error every time (Only in android). I have added all the additional codes that are given in the documentation.

My `react-native` version is: **0.66.3**

And `react-native-video` version is: **5.2.0**

Is there any way to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

jCenter does not allow to update package anymore, all other packages should be taken from mavenCentral.

You can add jcenter to **android/build.gradle** like this:

```js
allprojects {
    repositories {
        .... # rest of your code
        jcenter() {
            content {
                includeModule("com.yqritc", "android-scalablevideoview")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to add jcenter to all your project nor use a forked library, you can patch the package on your project with [patch-package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/patch-package).
For this :

1. go to `node_modules/react-native-video/android/build.gradle` and add the below fix to your package

```
diff --git a/node_modules/react-native-video/android/build.gradle b/node_modules/react-native-video/android/build.gradle
index 2fb8dfd..eb7ecdf 100644
--- a/node_modules/react-native-video/android/build.gradle
+++ b/node_modules/react-native-video/android/build.gradle
@@ -19,8 +19,12 @@ android {
     }
 }
 
+repositories {
+    maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
+}
+
 dependencies {
     //noinspection GradleDynamicVersion
     implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:${safeExtGet('reactNativeVersion', '+')}"
-    implementation 'com.yqritc:android-scalablevideoview:1.0.4'
+    implementation 'com.github.MatrixFrog:android-scalablevideoview:v1.0.4-jitpack'
 }
```

2. run `npx patch-package react-native-video` to apply the patch to your project
3. Finish the patch-package setup on your project
4. rebuild your android project with `yarn android`

Comment: The best answer, no need to modify my current source code

Comment: I would upvote this answer 10 times if I could. I can't even express how much I hate to make modifications to my own code as a workaround for a bug in some random package that I will eventually forget to revert when the package gets an update. You made my day bro! :)

Answer (score 3):

This issue seems to happen with `react-native-video`. For those who are having issues with `jcenter()` being deprecated, heres how to resolve:

1. replace `react-native-video` in `package.json` with
   `"react-native-video": "https://github.com/MatrixFrog/react-native-video#11ca8a6799f932a5f24da85dfe68c696ad13a753"`
2. In `android/build.gradle`, add `maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }` in repositories, it should look like:

```
allprojects {
        repositories {
            ...
            maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }
        }
    }
```

3. In `android/app/build.gradle` add            `implementation 'com.github.MatrixFrog:Android-ScalableVideoView:v1.0.4-jitpack'`
4. delete your `package-lock.json` and `node_modules`, and reinstall.
5. clean/rebuild in android studio.

and voala.

Answer (score 0):

`react-native-video` is currently sourcing from `google` repository on version 6.0.0.alpha.